# ¿Cómo capturar el evento desconexión del cliente durante una llamada Ajax en AspNet/ Net Core?

Tags: ajax, asp.net, http, asp.net-core

Se me presento el siguiente escenario:

- Durante una llamada Ajax el proceso en el controlador demoraría 10 minutos, al usuario por algún motivos se le apaga la PC, o simplemente cierra el navegador o recarga la página.

*Debugeando* veo que el proceso sigue corriendo en el servidor y cuando finaliza recién se dan cuenta que no tiene a quien devolverle el response.

A lo cual me estaría consumiendo recursos del servidor sin sentido.

¿Hay alguna forma de detectar esto durante cualquier **request**?

Hablando del stack .ASP Net MVC Full Framework +4
Y Net core 2+

Saludos.

Comment: no.. salvo que hagas una especie de keep alive durante tu procesos en el server que le pregunte al cliente si sigue esperando...

Comment: y para eso podría usar SignalR y algún token de cancelación por parte del server :D

Comment: Yo implementé una solución para este caso y similares en [tag:php], tomando como referencia el modelo de batch usado por Drupal6x y Drupal7x, la estrategia usada puede serte útil. No la copio como respuesta por no ser [tag:ASP] si consideras pertinente que la publique, con mucho gusto la propongo.

Answer (score 1):

Te explico, cuando se realiza una llamada Ajax al servidor el servidor por lo general no tiene contexto de que esta sucediendo en el cliente, lo que se me ocurre es interceptar el cierre del navegador y asociar un id uno idempotente a la transacción para detener el proceso de servidor, pero quedarían pendientes los escenarios de apagado del computador.

Me parece que la solución mas apropiada y conocida es la de los challenges o mensajes echo, en las que durante la duración del proceso el servidor envía un "Challenge" o un mensaje "echo" que el cliente debe responder inmediatamente al recibirlos, de esta manera el servidor puede saber si aun tiene un cliente activo esperando.

En términos prácticos, podrías abrir un websocket para este fin entre el servidor y el cliente, usando un identificador único para saber saber por que transacción en especifico se esta consultando.